# Best way to get runtime Type of T?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Given the example code below, I'd like to get the runtime type of T inside a generic method (in this case retrieveData).  When I create an XMLFilePersisting I use the interface, namely ITransferable rather than the implementing Types since in my client I want to have a list of all of them together:

```
List<XMLFilePersisting<ITransferable>> allThem;
```

So if in retrieveData I do typeof(T) that should return ITransferable which doesn't give me enough info to load the items from the file.  The only way I could figure out how to do this was by passing an instance of the implementor of ITransferable in the constructor, but this kind of feels like there should be a better way.  Suggestions?

```
public interface IPersisting<T> {
        List<T> retrieveData();
        bool persistData(List<T> lst);
    }

public interface ITransferable {
    Type getRuntimeType();
}

public class XMLFilePersisting<T> : IPersisting<T> where T : ITransferable {
    private readonly T defaultT;
    //...
    public XMLFilePersisting(string thefile, string thepath, T def) {
        //...
        defaultT = def;
    }
    ...

    public List<T> retrieveData() {
      List<T> retVal = new List<T>();
      Type runType = defaultT.getRuntimeType();
      string elemName = runType.Name;
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FQ_FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs)) {
           //below line won't work, typeof resolves at compileTime      
           //XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
           XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(runType);
           if (reader.ReadToFollowing(elemName)) { //go to the first test, skipping over ListofT
              do {
                 T testVal = (T)xmlSer.Deserialize(reader);
                 retVal.Add(testVal);
                }
              while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(elemName));
           }
         } //end using xmlreader
      } //end using FileStream
    return retVal;
  } //end retrieveData
} //end class XMLFilePersisting
```

Additional info:

Client code looks like below.  As you can see I need all

```
IPersisting<ITransferable>
```

instances, but the problem is in retrieveData, that makes typeof(T) = ITransferable which doesn't give me enough info to do the deserialization.  That is why I pass concrete implmentations of ITransferable to the constructor (MyClass1, MyClass2).  This seems to work, but feels like a hack.

```
IPersisting<ITransferable> xfpMC1 = new XMLFilePersisting<ITransferable>("persistedMC1.xml", myTempDirectory, new MyClass1());
IPersisting<ITransferable> xfpMC2 = new XMLFilePersisting<ITransferable>("persistedMC2.xml", myTempDirectory, new MyClass2());
```

A

Comment: First thing to change: start following .NET naming conventions. It'll make it simpler for others to read your code, if you meet their naming expectations.

Comment: Next, it's not at all clear where you would be passing the information about which actual type you want. Your "When I create an XMLFilePersisting I use the interface, namely ITransferable rather than the implementing Types since in my client I want to have a list of all of them together" doesn't explain much to me. Are you creating multiple instances of `XMLFilePersisting`? If so, why not create a single instance for each concrete type, then build a big `List<ITransferable>` from the results?

Comment: Sorry.  I edited my question to better show the relevant part from my calling code

Comment: Well we still don't know why you want them to be `IPersisting<ITransferable>` rather than an `IPersisting<MyClass1>` and an `IPersisting<MyClass2>` which would obviously solve the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet at the end of the day I'd prefer they all go into a single strongly typed List

Comment: So do that afterwards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you make each `XMLFilePersisting` use the specific concrete type, but then combine the results into a `List<ITransferable>`. For example:

```
// Names changed to be more conventional
var class1Loader = new XmlFilePersister<MyClass1>("MC1.xml", myTempDirectory");
var class2Loader = new XmlFilePersister<MyClass2>("MC2.xml", myTempDirectory");

// Could do all of this in one statement... note that this uses the
// covariance of IEnumerable<T>
IEnumerable<ITransferable> class1Results = class1Loader.RetrieveData();
IEnumerable<ITransferable> class2Results = class2Loader.RetrieveData();
var allResults = class1Results.Concat(class2Results).ToList();
```

Having misunderstood the question slightly, if it's the *persisters* you want to be in a list, you could make `XMLFilePersisting<T>` implement `IPersisting<ITransferable>` - although then you'd have problems when you try to *store* the data instead of reading it... because you'd need to cast from `ITransferable` to `T`, which could obviously fail at execution time.

Fundamentally, I wonder whether you should have two interfaces: `IDeserializer<out T>` and `ISerializer<in T>`. With those covariant and contravariant interfaces, you could easily have a `List<IDeserializer<ITransferable>>` without losing information or needing execution-time checking.

Comment: do you have a typo, when twice call `class1Loader.RetrieveData();`  and for `class2Results ` should be called `class2Loader.RetrieveData();`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will work for me as I need a `List<IPersisting<ITransferable>>` rather than a `List<ITransferable>`.  Since IPersisting is invariant (right?) I can't upcast from `XMLFilePersisting<MyClass1>` to `IPersisting<ITransferable>`   Other threads have pointed to reflection but I'd rather just stay with my 'hack' of storing an arbitrary T reference.

Comment: @publicwireless: Ah, I see. How about making `XMLFilePersisting<T>` just implement `IPersisting<ITransferable>`? Or you *could* make it generic in two types... it's a bit hard to tell without knowing more context.

Comment: @publicwireless: I've edited my answer to give a bit more detail.